# Viminfo truncates named registers. Setting to increase limit?

Tags: register, viminfo

I save quite a few lines into a named register `"iy100l`. I can then paste from that register just fine, `"ip`.

I close and reopen Vim then try to paste from that register again `"ip` but it's truncated to only 50 lines.

So I'm guessing `.viminfo` has a limit on the length of registers it will save but I couldn't find it documented. Is there a setting to increase the limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be configured with the `"` character of the `viminfo` option

From `:help 'viminfo`:

```
"   Maximum number of lines saved for each register.  Old name of
    the '<' item, with the disadvantage that you need to put a
    backslash before the ", otherwise it will be recognized as the
    start of a comment!
```

Comment: Details on those settings aren't directly under `:help viminfo` hence not finding them before, but your answer did set me looking in the right direction, clicking through to the `viminfo` option which can be directly accessed by `:help 'viminfo'` (note the apostrophes).

Comment: Yes, true. Though the leading apostrophe is enough

Answer (score 3):

`:help viminfo` contains general information on the feature but not settings.

`:help 'viminfo'` (note the apostrophes) is the documentation on the actual option settings. The key bit is `<` which sets the max lines saved per register. You are also forced to set a value for `'` (max files marks are saved for). While I was at it I increased `s` (max Kbytes saved per register).

So the bit you stick in your `.vimrc`:

`set viminfo='50,<200,s100`

Comment: As `:help 'viminfo'` says, the key bit is `<` rather than `"` because the latter is essentially deprecated. I'm preferring this answer to @Naumann's answer because his is a bit misleading unless he changes it.